# Oracle: Constraints of keys

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an entity within Oracle's SQL:

[image]

and I'm wondering, what does "UF" represent? I've written the SQL code but I do not know how to represent the "UF" attribute as a constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE entry (
    entryno           NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    carndate          DATE NOT NULL,
    entrystarttime    DATE NOT NULL,
    entryfinishtime   DATE NOT NULL,
    entryplace        NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    charname          VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    compno            NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    eventypecode      CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    teamname          VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE entry ADD CONSTRAINT entry_pk PRIMARY KEY ( entryno,     
                                                        carndate );

ALTER TABLE entry
    ADD CONSTRAINT entry_charity_fk FOREIGN KEY ( charname )
        REFERENCES charity ( charname );

ALTER TABLE entry
    ADD CONSTRAINT entry_carnival_fk FOREIGN KEY ( carndate )
        REFERENCES carnival ( carndate );

ALTER TABLE entry                       #
    ADD CONSTRAINT entry_competitor_fk FOREIGN KEY ( compno )
        REFERENCES competitor ( compno );

ALTER TABLE entry                       #
    ADD CONSTRAINT entry_event_fk FOREIGN KEY ( carndate, eventypecode )
        REFERENCES evenet ( carndate, eventypecode );

ALTER TABLE entry
    ADD CONSTRAINT entry_team_fk FOREIGN KEY ( teamname, carndate )
        REFERENCES team ( teamname,carndate );

ALTER TABLE entry
    ADD CONSTRAINT ... ("UF")
```

Comment: I guess UF doesn't have any meaning here. might it is something for notification.

Comment: @vivek - actually it does have a meaning

Comment: okay got it, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *UF* is actually two flags.

As you've recognised the *F* means the column is a foreign key. The *U* stands for Unique. Those columns form part of the compound unique key:

```
ALTER TABLE entry ADD CONSTRAINT entry_carnival_un UNIQUE
                                                ( carndate, compno, eventypecode );
```

`carndate` is also part of the compound primary key so really it should be flagged *PFU* but I guess the modelling tool didn't allow for three flags.

Comment: @APC thanks a lot. Do i have to include the REFERENCE clause after the ADD CONSTRAINT? also, i've added a hash in the sql code because i want to ask if those lines were necessary? I was testing those two lines earlier and forgotten to remove them.

Comment: Foreign keys require the REFERENCES clause, because that defines the parent table.

Comment: @APC so in the case of Unique, it's going to be REFERENCES carnival, competitor, event ( carndate, compno, eventypecode );?

Comment: No, UNIQUE keys aren't foreign keys.